# Как уменьшить время запросов?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть запрос к api, который выполняется очень долго (получаю инфу о складах, много инфы)

```
warehouses = codes.map do |code|
  data = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(URI.encode("http://endpoint.de?параметр=#{code}")))
  JSON.parse(data)
end
```

`codes` - содержит коды городов
`data` - вся инфа о конкретном складе в выбранном городе
`warehouses` - массив со складами в выбранном по codes городу

Для города, где таких складов 4, понятное дело, строится быстро. Но в Мск их 219 и строится может до 30 секунд.
В базе сохранять можно, как вариант. Но я хотел бы узнать:
**1)** как и где еще можно хранить эти данные? чтобы сократить время запросов. Или все таки лучше в базе.
**2)** можно как-то оптимизировать код?

**UPD:** Логика такая
1) выбираю селектом город
2) код города отправляется в экшн
3) в экшне строю склады и их описание
4) отображаю на карте

Comment: Рассматриваете возможность кэширования? Если да, можете дополнить вопрос, что можно кэшировать (эндпоинт, сам ответ ручки) и как долго?

Comment: если кэширование тут возможно, то, конечно. Единственный момент - что кэшировать? 1) я выбираю селект, 2) аяксом отправляю запрос на экшн, 3) там строю эти склады и 4) отображаю склады на карте